# ytFiles is null in youtubeExtractor "onExtractionComplete" func

Tags: java

I am using the "youtube extractor" library in my Android Studio music project and previously used the "master-SNAPSHOT" version. However, since encountering an issue, I switched to version "v2.1.0". Now, I am having problems with the "ytFiles" variable, which is returning null instead of containing information about the YouTube video. Can anyone assist me with this issue? The relevant code is as follows:

```
implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v2.1.0'
```

my java code:

```
    YouTubeExtractor somxt = new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
        @Override
        protected void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta videoMeta) {
            List<Integer> iTags = Arrays.asList(249);//download it as a webm type

            for (Integer iTag : iTags) {

                YtFile ytFile = ytFiles.get(iTag);
                try {

                    if (ytFile != null) {

                        String downloadUrl = ytFile.getUrl();

                        if (downloadUrl != null && !downloadUrl.isEmpty()) {

                            Toast.makeText(downloadSong.this, "Download started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            downloadSong(downloadUrl, name + ".webm");//start the download of the song
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(downloadSong.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```